# Изменение класса при смене содержимого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

При выборе опции товара (переключение пунктов списка) происходит изменение остатков. При нулевом остатке должен меняться класс одного из блоков. Конструкция выглядит примерно так:

```
<div class="stock">10</div>

<div class="buy-now">
<span>Купить нельзя</span>
<button>Купить</button>
</div>

<ul>
    <li>Значение 1</li>
    <li>Значение 2</li>
</ul>

<style>
    .buy-now span, .buy-now.hide button {display: none;}
    .buy-now.hide span {display: block;}
</style>
```

Например, выбираем "Значение 2" и цифра в блоке .stock изменяется на 0. Нужен скрипт, который будет отслеживать постоянно изменение содержимого блока и при появлении в нем "0" добавлял или убирал класс .hide для блока .buy-now

Я пробовал привязать условие на клик маркированного списка, но он срабатывает со второго нажатия. В общем-то, можно его отслеживать постоянно, не привязывая к действиям пользователя?

Comment: _Я пробовал привязать условие на клик маркированного списка, но он срабатывает со второго нажатия._ - как-то не правильно пробовал.

Comment: Для постоянного отслеживания html узла, можно посмотреть в сторону [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Дело в том, что по клику сперва данные вносятся в блок stock. То есть, он то по умолчанию имеет значение 10, при клике изменяется на 0. Тут же и условие срабатывает, но значение то по клику было не ноль, которое стало таковым, а 10. В итоге результат условия правильно срабатывает после второго нажатия.

Comment: @Grundy спорим, что он "пробовал привязать условие **в** клике маркированного списка"?

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, нужен код, по объяснению ничего не понятно

Comment: @Igor, что ты хочешь проиграть? :-)

Comment: @Grundy "это только пацаны на щелобаны играют, а настоящие игроки - на интерес"

Comment: @Igor пробовал и вопрос удалось решить через банальный timeout. Вопрос оставлю на случай, если кто-то предложит иное решение. Просто для обучения.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev - "Вы погубите себя, мой юный друг!" Дюма. Использованием timeout'ов для борьбы с асинхронностью вымощена дорога в ад. (это уже я)

Comment: @Igor есть иной упрощенный вариант? Предположим, что значение в .stock выбирается одним из пунктов маркированного списка. Нажал на первое значение - осталось 10. Нажал на второе - 0. Как при появлении нуля добавить класс в .buy-now? Залезть в скрипт изменяющий значение нельзя. Фактически, привязаться можно только к пункту списка или как-то динамически отслеживать.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Мне, пока что, приходитсдя гадать, что происходит у Вас коде. Полагаю, что значение в `.stock` обновляется через запрос к серверу.

Comment: @Igor так и есть. При выборе опции, запрашивается остаток и подставляется значение.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Может, покажете код? Нам обоим будет легче :).